# How to publish subtitles on YouTube as a viewer

Tags: youtube, subtitles

It was possible to publish subtitles using different YouTube accounts under the same Gmail.

YouTube requires ~5/6 YouTube accounts to confirm a draft before publishing the subtitles, but it is no longer possible. Did the mechanism changed?

Can anyone confirm?
What's the current requirement for publishing subtitles?
Is there a way to publish subtitles as a viewer with only 1 Gmail account now?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, due to some young [abuser](https://www.theverge.com/2019/9/2/20844910/youtube-translation-changes-jt-pewdiepie-harassment) who abused the translation system, YouTube has changed the rules. Under the new rules, contributed translations won’t be published to YouTube until **the channel owner has manually approved them**.

Hopefully, YouTube can figure out a smarter automatic publish mechanism later.